# Android Library in React-native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to implement an android Library in React native.
I do not understand how to import this Library to my react project. Where will the native android code go in my react project??
I tried to manually paste the Android Library in my project but the project does not compile, cannot resolve a lot of symbols.
I know how to bridge a native code in react but the Android Library just wont compile inside my project.
Is there an easy way to this or do i rewrite the Library to fit into the react native project??

Comment: Does the library already have a class that implements the React bridge?

Comment: @BradBumbalough no, Its a simple android library, the google VR cardboard library to be specefic. Now, how do i resolve the native dependencies in my react native project.

Comment: I'm assuming you've read these docs? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Comment: hey did you find a solution for this ? i have to do it myself in my project with another android library for both iOS and android using react native .. if you did please answer your question or edit it with the solution  .. thank you